# Dask equivalent to pandas.DataFrame.update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a few functions that are using `pandas.DataFrame.update` method, and I'm trying to move into using `Dask` instead for the datasets, but the Dask Pandas API doesn't have the `update` method implemented. Is there an alternative way to get the same result in `Dask`?

Here are the methods I have using `update`:

1. Forward fills data with last known value

`df.update(df.filter(like='/').mask(lambda x: x == 0).ffill(1))`

input

```
id .. .. ..(some cols) 1/1/20 1/2/20 1/3/20 1/4/20 1/5/20 1/6/20 ....
1                      10     20     0      40     0      50
2                      10     30     30     0      0      50
.
.
```

output

```
id .. .. ..(some cols) 1/1/20 1/2/20 1/3/20 1/4/20 1/5/20 1/6/20 ....
1                      10     20     20     40     40      50
2                      10     30     30     30     30      50
.
.
```

2. Replaces values in a dataframe with values from another dataframe based on an id/index column

```
def replace_names(df1, df2, idxCol = 'id', srcCol = 'name', dstCol = 'name'):
    df1 = df1.set_index(idxCol)
    df1[dstCol].update(df2.set_index(idxCol)[srcCol])
    return df1.reset_index()
df_new = replace_names(df1, df2)
```

input

df1

```
id    name  ...
123   city a
456   city b
789   city c
789   city c
456   city b
123   city a
.
.
.
```

df2

```
id    name  ...
123   City A
456   City B
789   City C
.
.
.
```

output

```
id    name  ...
123   City A
456   City B
789   City C
789   City C
456   City B
123   City A
.
.
.
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular sample of data and its output.

Comment: updated with examples of input and output. Would like a general replacement function for `pandas.Dataframe.update`

Comment: It seems to me that `update` by default use a left join I think you could implement without using `update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 2

There is a way to partially solve this. I'm assuming that `df2` is much smaller than `df1` and it actually fit in memory so we can read as pandas dataframe. If this is the case the following function work if `df1` is a `pandas` or a `dask` dataframe but `df2`should be a `pandas` one.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

def replace_names(df1, # can be pandas or dask dataframe
                  df2, # this should be pandas.
                  idxCol='id',
                  srcCol='name',
                  dstCol='name'):
    diz = df2[[idxCol, srcCol]].set_index(idxCol).to_dict()[srcCol]
    out = df1.copy()
    out[dstCol] = out[idxCol].map(diz)
    return out
```

## Question 1

Regarding the first problem the following code works in `pandas` and `dask`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 2},
 'b': {0: 3, 1: 4},
 '1/1/20': {0: 10, 1: 10},
 '1/2/20': {0: 20, 1: 30},
 '1/3/20': {0: 0, 1: 30},
 '1/4/20': {0: 40, 1: 0},
 '1/5/20': {0: 0, 1: 0},
 '1/6/20': {0: 50, 1: 50}})

# if you want to try with dask
# df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

cols = [col for col in df.columns if "/" in col]
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(lambda x: x==0).ffill(1) #.astype(int)
```

Remove the comment in the last line if you want the output to be integer.

**UPDATE Question 2**
In case you want a `dask` only solution you could try the following.

### Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 123, 1: 456, 2: 789, 3: 789, 4: 456, 5: 123},
 'name': {0: 'city a',
  1: 'city b',
  2: 'city c',
  3: 'city c',
  4: 'city b',
  5: 'city a'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 123, 1: 456, 2: 789},
 'name': {0: 'City A', 1: 'City B', 2: 'City C'}})

df1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=2)
df2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=2)
```

### Case 1

In this case if one `id` is present in `df1` but not in `df2` you keep the name in `df1`.

```py
def replace_names_dask(df1, df2,
                       idxCol='id',
                       srcCol='name',
                       dstCol='name'):
    if srcCol == dstCol:
        df2 = df2.rename(columns={srcCol:f"{srcCol}_new"})
        srcCol = f"{srcCol}_new"
    
    def map_replace(x, srcCol, dstCol):
        x[dstCol] = np.where(x[srcCol].notnull(),
                             x[srcCol],
                             x[dstCol])
        return x
    
    df = dd.merge(df1, df2, on=idxCol, how="left")
    df = df.map_partitions(lambda x: map_replace(x, srcCol, dstCol))
    df = df.drop(srcCol, axis=1)
    return df

df = replace_names_dask(df1, df2)
```

### Case 2

In this case if one `id` is present in `df1` but not in `df2` then `name` in the output `df` will be `NaN` (as in a standard left join)

```py
def replace_names_dask(df1, df2,
                       idxCol='id',
                       srcCol='name',
                       dstCol='name'):
    df1 = df1.drop(dstCol, axis=1)
    df2 = df2.rename(columns={srcCol: dstCol})
    df = dd.merge(df1, df2, on=idxCol, how="left")
    return df

df = replace_names_dask(df1, df2)
```

Comment: For Question 2, is there a way to have both as dask dataframes since these are part of a much larger class where these dfs are processed and I would like to keep everything in `Dask` if possible

Comment: @codingenthusiast I added a dask only solution.